# jQuery TokenInput with POST method(remote json data)

Tags: json, autocomplete, http-post, jquery-tokeninput

Recently I've found jQuery Tokeninput plugin to be the most accurate solution for my project, where one need to enter multiple user names to fill one form.
I've read docs for this plugin and found that it is possible to override send method from GET to POST. Because I already use a library producing clean and valid json from DB,I thought it was enough to implement and use Tokeninput successfully. Instead it turned out that although plugin gives a possibility to override send method, it constantly uses GET.

Here is a piece of data I'm using to provide data to plugin:

```
{"d":[{"username":"Jordan Jelena","email":"jelena@sth.com","tel":"000000000","sms":"000000000@text"},{"username":"Ford Alison","email":"alison@sth.com","tel":"000000000","sms":"000000000@text"}]}
```

This is how I use Tokeninput:
js:

```
$("#test").tokenInput("Email.aspx/GetData", {
        contentType: "json",
        theme: 'facebook',
        hintText: 'Enter Lastname',
        searchingText: 'Searching...',
        method: 'POST',
        queryParam: 'q',
        minChars: 3
        preventDuplicates: true,
        propertyToSearch: 'username',
        animateDropdown: false
});
```

html:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="test">1: </label>
  <input id="test" size="60" />
</div>
```

I already googled the internet for a solution but found nothing useful. It seems that everyone is using GET method.. Is there any way to make this plugin work with POST ??

I managed to trace the output of the plugin and what I find every time is q=. It does not populate any data from the source. The only thing it does for now, is look slick and shows nice hints.

Useful hints are welcome :)

Comment: Returning that JSON won't work no, but I'm presuming you're not returning that, if your code previously worked using GET? Can you provide a link or jsFiddle?

Comment: Sorry, no time for fiddle this time. I'm looking for working solution with Tokeninput where data source is remote eg. comes from webmethod with json output. Data I provided is sufficient for overview of a problem. I'm looking for a thought I did't come up with :)

Comment: I beg to differ! What do you mean, by "Here is a piece of data I'm using to provide data to plugin:" - is that what your server side page returns? Is that what you're providing your server-side page? What does it return, when you send it requests outside of the tokeninput? What are you testing with? From what I can see, your js and html look fine, hence why I'm asking for more information.

Comment: The json data above is an output from my webmethod which is the data source for tokeninput. Setting tokeninput contentType: 'application/json' does not work - I trace the request app<->srv in httpfox(ff plugin) and the request header contains Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 which is odd.. and that's why the server does not return json.
I ran some tests and found that when I call webmethod using $.ajax, I get clean json. When I call webmethod from tokeninput it always gets xml.